# Error in the following piece of code

Tags: c

I am wondering why this piece of code is not working properly. Rms is the value calculated by some processing and comes out to be 0.000146 and I want to see the result as Test passed, but I get test failed. What is wrong any suggestions?

```
 If(rms <0.001){
    return Test_PASSED
    }
    else{
    return Test_FAILED
    }
```

Test_PASSED and TEST_FAILED is a enumeration defined as follows:

//! Possible test results
`typedef enum`

`{`

`Test_PASSED = 0, //!< passed`

`Test_FAILED = -1 //!< failed`

`} Test_Result_e;`

Comment: We need to see more code. We don't even know the type of rms.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @BinayakaChakraborty How does that apply here?

Comment: @Paulpro rms is just a floating point value. Its just a condition. Rms has a value of 0.000146. I have mentioned it.

Comment: Floating points are being compared, on a very high amount of threshold ( e^-6), as such this may apply. Also, we need to see the full code for more detailed analysis

Comment: is your `rms` is of type `float`? then suffix `0.001` with an `f`---> `0.001f`

Comment: @DX What do you mean by floating point value... Is it a `float` or a `double` or what?

Comment: We probably need more code... Can you do this for me: `printf("%d\n", sizeof(float));` I'm ASSUMING you're running this on a computer where this will yield 4... but on some micro-processors, it will be 2.  Which could make a difference.

Comment: @DX:  Is rms a `float`?  Because 0.001 is *not*, it is a `double`.  Comparing `float` and `double` only leads to tears.  Try `0.001f`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to suffix `float` constants with `f`. I assume your variable `rms` is of type `float`. Because, constant `0.001` will implicitly have `double` type precision.

If I'm correct the following should work.

```
   if(rms <0.001f){
    return TestPassed
    }
    else{
    return testFailed
    }
```

Comment: nope its not I already tried it.

Comment: @DX I see, then please post some more code... in it's current form it's difficult to tell the error.....

Answer (score 0):

The original question didn't specify what `Test_PASSED` or `Test_FAILED` are.  But one possible bug was that they were accidentally set to the same thing.

Another possible bug is the way that they're being tested, e.g. confusion between `==` and `=`.

Comment: `Test_PASSED` and `Test_FAILED` are different to `TestPassed` and `testFailed`.  I think you should post all the relevant code.

Comment: see my edit. I have mentioned it.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  More code would help.  Also, how do you know that rms is the value you say it is?

Answer (score 0):

The if is written with upper case i, this is incorrect. Statements inside the if block are not finished with ;

The code should have been

```
if (rms < 0.001) {
    return TestPassed;
}
else {
    return testFailed;
}
```

Still, it's not clear what TestPassed and testFailed are - you copied an incomplete piece of code. Probably you missed spelling of one of them too.

Finally, it seems that the biggest problem is that you're learning programming in general using C. There are much better languages for that. Any modern high level programming language would be better. Try, for example, python or ruby.